# How to display tooltip for each column of a list in the datasheet view in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a `list` in sharepoint with some columns like

```
Name | Job Description | Location

xxxx      xxxxxxx          xxxxx
aaa        aaaaa            aaa
```

I require this list to be displayed in `Datasheet View`, which i have done. 
While creating this list, i added a description for each column, is there anyway to show it as a `tooltip` when the user hovers over each column? Can this be done using sharepoint/sharepoint designer?

Comment: Not sure if applicable, but the title-property of HTML elements is great for this

Answer (score 1):

The Datasheet view is a spin-off of Access, served as a web app in a web page. The elements of the Datasheet view are not configurable with the GUI or SharePoint Designer, as far as I know. The web app even mis-behaves with a lot of other screen elements and is hard to control.

You may want to add another web part above the Datasheet view to display hover effects and tooltips.